# How to make own Wi-Fi panel server like Hotels or Airports?

Tags: wireless-networking, dns

I was in an airport, and there were bunch of free Wi-Fi networks, when I connected to one of them it shows me a nice panel and shows welcome page and so on.

another time in a hotel again when I connected to their network shows me nice panel and their logo and so on.

The question is what is the name of that and how to make ?

Comment: Do you have the hardware that supports this?

Comment: [Captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). Please don't do this, it hinders users trying to do their business. Also, it will cause problems with HTTPS sites.

Comment: @LPChip, yes I have access point and personal server.

Comment: @gronostaj, thanks interesting, do you have any tutorial to make ? rep ++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referred to as a "[*Captive Portal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)".

To be effective, you'll need to implement access controls and authentication on the/a router. Some higher-end models will provide this functionality for you.

I'd strongly encourage you to avoid doing this if at all possible:

- From a security / access control point of view they are often fairly trivial to get around (for example by tunnelling traffic via DNS requests, which is often not blocked or suitably constrained)
- From a usability point of view, they offer a very poor experience with no real gain - just getting the "*login page*" to display correctly can be temperamental.
- Often other non-web applications will mysteriously fail with strange errors (e.g: Games / VoIP / etc...)
- Any site on an HSTS preload list will fail to operate for reasons that are unclear to a typical user.
- Many captive portals use HTTPS with a self-signed certificate, which will (should) deter users... additionally users should *not* be expected to just "*click continue*" just to login to your portal.
- Many captive portals make use of unsuitable addresses (such as `1.1.1.1`, looking at you Cisco), making whole swathes of the modern internet inaccessible.

If you *really* want to set one up, then there are plenty of tutorials around outlining the steps required.

Comment: thank you so much , would you please give me a quick tutorial to test? I've router and private ip and personal server, I wanna test this on my iPhone 7.

Comment: Try searching for "_captive portal raspberry pi_"... A typical consumer router will not likely support this... what is a "_personal server_"?

Comment: Apologies for my typo... either way, what's that? A machine at home? A machine in a datacenter (colo)? A VPS?

Comment: Means I've dedicate Server and I can create my own DNS server to connect

Comment: Just to be clear "_Questions seeking product, service, or **learning material** recommendations are off-topic ..._"