# PfSense captive portal HTTPS

Tags: https, pfsense

I am having trouble enabling HTTPS on my captive portal. I've already done certificates like so:
[CA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZGuJ.png)
[Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qivRT.png)
[DNS resolver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjKpb.png)
[HTTPS captive portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLtHk.png)

but my captive portal still doesnt show up and give me error. Am i missing something? Can someone please help?

Comment: Don't use a captive portal?... https://superuser.com/a/1422842/707676

Comment: @Attie I'm trying to create a guest login which requires voucher to access the wifi....

Comment: Read the points in the linked answer - they are a poor choice for managing WiFi access and in many cases are fundamentally broken... look into other options - perhaps [RADIUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) can help?

Comment: @Attie Thank you for your time.. but however the reason i need to use captive portal is because i'm using a custom login page which able to detect QR code from the mobile cameras or webcams.. In order to activate this functionality, I need to use HTTPS

Comment: @Attie My previous question has been solved with just HTTP alone.. but this time i need to use HTTPS

Comment: That sounds overly complex... do your users a favour and avoid a captive portal - your "_it's not working properly_" request for help just highlights one of the **fundamental** issues with captive portals.